# How to draw software architecture in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to generate something like this in Latex

[image]

I've already checked [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350729/software-architecture-picture-in-tikz) but wasn't able to generate something visually appealing.

I just need a general idea on how to do it on my own, you don't need to post the whole picture (also no problem if you want to :) )

Comment: they are all simple rectangles. Which part is difficult?

Comment: Can you share your attempts which did result in something not visually appealing?

Comment: One approach: use `tcolorbox` and `tcbraster`, but please show what you've done so far.