# Draw layered software architecture with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to represent a layered software architecture.
There is already an interesting [approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350739/31407) on this site. But I can't add small boxes to the bottom (to be exact: one more row, containing two boxes of equal size).

---

[image: Layered architecture]

```
\documentclass[border=2px]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, calc}

\tikzset{
    green/.style  = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=1.2cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    blue/.style   = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=8cm+3\pgflinewidth, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5.0cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    yellow/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=8cm+3\pgflinewidth, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5.0cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=yellow!30},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going right,
  start chain=2 going below, node distance=1mm]
  \node [name=r1c1, on chain=1, green] {VC++};
  \node [name=r1c2, on chain=1, green] {VB.NET};
  \node [name=r1c3, on chain=1, green] {C\#.NET};
  \node [name=r1c4, on chain=1, green] {Others};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  node [name=r2c1, on chain=2, blue, anchor=north west, yshift=-1mm,
  minimum width=\n1-\pgflinewidth]
  at (r1c1.south west) {COM-API Interface};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  node [name=r3c1, on chain=2, yellow, minimum width=\n1-\pgflinewidth] {Autodesk Inventor Application};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

<sup>This code is not my own. It is copied from the link above.</sup>

Comment: You could use the `fit` library for the outer line of all nodes and define some node styles.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't know anything about TikZ. The code is not mine (I've added a disclaimer now).

Comment: See my answer. I've done it for you …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2px]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, chains, calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    green/.style  = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=1.2cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    blue/.style   = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=8cm+3\pgflinewidth, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5.0cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    yellow/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum width=8cm+3\pgflinewidth, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5.0cm, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=yellow!30},
    red/.style={minimum height=1cm, text centered, font=\footnotesize, draw=black, fill=red!30}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going right,
  start chain=2 going below, node distance=1mm]
  \node [name=r1c1, on chain=1, green] {VC++};
  \node [name=r1c2, on chain=1, green] {VB.NET};
  \node [name=r1c3, on chain=1, green] {C\#.NET};
  \node [name=r1c4, on chain=1, green] {Others};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  node [name=r2c1, on chain=2, blue, anchor=north west, yshift=-1mm,
  minimum width=\n1-\pgflinewidth]
  at (r1c1.south west) {COM-API Interface};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  node [name=r3c1, on chain=2, yellow, minimum width=\n1-\pgflinewidth] {Autodesk Inventor Application};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$),
  \p2=($(r1c1.east)-(r1c2.west)$), \n1 ={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2={\x2} in
  node [name=r4c1, on chain=2, red,xshift=-0.25*(\n1+2*\pgflinewidth-0.5*\n2), 
  minimum width=0.5*(\n1-\pgflinewidth+\n2)] {Pffft};
  \draw let \p1=($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$),
  \p2=($(r1c1.east)-(r1c2.west)$), \n1 ={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2={\x2} in
  node[right=1mm of r4c1,
  name=r4c2, red,minimum width=0.5*(\n1-\pgflinewidth+\n2)] {Pfffft};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the great ligatures in the last row ;)

Comment: @Max This is marmot language. You need to pronounce it as "Pffft". ;-)

Comment: @marmot but... but... that's Billy the (lobotomized) cat! http://abcs-of-art.blogspot.com/2007/09/letter-p-i-chose-pfft-for-p-as.html ;-P

Comment: @Rmano If you drop one f, the meaning changes completely. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Could you add some little explaining (or references)?

Comment: And is it advisable to use absolute values in order to change the columns within the rows without affecting other rows?

Comment: @mike I;ll be happy to add explanations if you give me a hint which aspect should be explained. And what do you mean by absolute values? What I did here is to se the calc library in order to in infer the dimensions from the upper rows and apply them to the lower rows. That way you only have to change one dimension in order to make a change, and do not have to adjust many things, which could be messy.

Comment: @marmot Okay, then I'll specify :) What are `\p1`, `\p2`, `\n1`, and `\n2`? I meant absolute coordinates -- your solution uses length relative to existing nodes. If I change some nodes (e.g. remove any from the first row), the following rows change. So I should either use absolute values oooor I should plan ahead better.

Comment: @mike Not, this is the calc syntax. What it does is to set the first point, `\p1`, to the difference between `(r1c4.east)` and `(r1c1.west)`. With this syntax, `\x1` will be the x-value of that difference, and `\y1` the y-value. `\n1` and `\n2` are then numbers derived from these coordinates. Specifically, `\n1` is the length (`veclen`) of the difference, and `\n2` is just the x-value of the second point `\p2`. I use the values to compute the shifts of the red boxes and their widths. So if you change the green boxes, the red boxes will automatically adjust themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
    \tikzstyle{s1} = [draw,minimum width=.9cm,minimum height=.7cm,fill=green!20]
    \tikzstyle{s2} = [draw,minimum width=6.15cm,minimum height=.7cm,fill=blue!20]
    \tikzstyle{s3} = [draw,minimum width=6.15cm,minimum height=.7cm,fill=yellow!20]
    \tikzstyle{s4} = [draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=.7cm,fill=red!20]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[s1] (a) {VC++};
        \node[s1,right=.1 of a] (b) {VB.NET};
        \node[s1,right=.1 of b] (c) {C\#.NET};
        \node[s1,right=.1 of c] (d) {Others};
            \node[s2,xshift=.87cm,below=.1 of b] (e) {COM-API Interface};
            \node[s3,below=.1 of e] (f) {Autodesk Inventor Application};
        \node[s4,below=.1 of f.south west,anchor=west,yshift=-.3cm] (foo) {Foo};
        \node[s4,right=.1 of foo,anchor=west] (bar) {Bar};
        \node[draw,fit=(a)(bar)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've got this ugly bug again. Could please someone format my code and add at the top of the text my famous "Hello!"? Thank you!

Comment: @marmot: What would I do without a marmot nearby me …

Comment: I've have to compliment you, because the code looks really clean. But I wanted to add one more row below containing two boxes of equal size. Is that possible with your solution? I guess I have to define `s4`?

Comment: @mike: Sorry, didn't read your question exactly, yeah, you're right. I'll fix that – give me a minute …

Comment: I guess the picture I've added was a little misleading in this context. Yes, thank you!

Comment: @mike: Is it so good?

Comment: Looks good, but concerning the code you might want to use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52379).

Answer (score 1):

for fun and exercised, a variation of the nice [marmot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer. by changes in definitions of the styles the code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, positioning}

\tikzset{
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{rectangle,
        minimum width=#1, fill=#2!30, draw,
        text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        minimum height=1cm, align=center,
        font=\footnotesize},
box/.default = 21mm/green,
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
                    ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={box, on chain}]
  \node (r1c1)  {VC++};
  \node (r1c2)  {VB.NET};
  \node (r1c3)  {C\#.NET};
  \node (r1c4)  {Others};
\end{scope}
\draw   let \p1 = ($(r1c4.east)-(r1c1.west)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    node (r2c1) [box=\n1/blue,
                 below=of $(r1c1.south)!0.5!(r1c4.south)$]
                 {COM-API Interface}
    node (r3c1) [box=\n1/yellow, below=of r2c1]
                {Autodesk Inventor Application};
\draw   let \p1 = ($(r1c2.east)-(r1c1.west)$),
            \n1 ={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    node (r4c1) [box=\n1/red, on chain,
                 below right=2mm and 0mm of r1c1.west |- r3c1.south] {aaaa}
    node (r4c1) [box=\n1/red, on chain] {bbbb};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]